# Part of Speech Tagger

Tags: php, natural-language-processing

I have a Part of Speech Tagger written in PHP that currently takes a relatively long and unpredictable time to execute - just wanted to know if any of you knew of any quick ways I can improve time efficiency in this class - not necessarily related to the algorithm itself, but even the construction of the PHP code.

```
<?php 
class PosTagger {
        private $dict; 

        public function __construct($lexicon) {
                $fh = fopen($lexicon, 'r');
                while($line = fgets($fh)) {
                        $tags = explode(' ', $line);
                        $this->dict[strtolower(array_shift($tags))] = $tags;
                }
                fclose($fh);
        }

        public function tag($text) {
                preg_match_all("/[\w\d\.]+/", $text, $matches);
                $nouns = array('NN', 'NNS');

                $return = array();
                $i = 0;
                foreach($matches[0] as $token) {
                        // default to a common noun
                        $return[$i] = array('token' => $token, 'tag' => 'NN');  

                        // remove trailing full stops
                        if(substr($token, -1) == '.') {
                                $token = preg_replace('/\.+$/', '', $token);
                        }

                        // get from dict if set
                        if(isset($this->dict[strtolower($token)])) {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = $this->dict[strtolower($token)][0];
                        }       

                        // Converts verbs after 'the' to nouns
                        if($i > 0) {
                                if($return[$i - 1]['tag'] == 'DT' && 
                                        in_array($return[$i]['tag'], 
                                                        array('VBD', 'VBP', 'VB'))) {
                                        $return[$i]['tag'] = 'NN';
                                }
                        }

                        // Convert noun to number if . appears
                        if($return[$i]['tag'][0] == 'N' && strpos($token, '.') !== false) {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'CD';
                        }

                        // Convert noun to past particile if ends with 'ed'
                        if($return[$i]['tag'][0] == 'N' && substr($token, -2) == 'ed') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VBN';
                        }

                        // Anything that ends 'ly' is an adverb
                        if(substr($token, -2) == 'ly') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'RB';
                        }

                        // Common noun to adjective if it ends with al
                        if(in_array($return[$i]['tag'], $nouns) 
                                                && substr($token, -2) == 'al') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'JJ';
                        }

                        // Noun to verb if the word before is 'would'
                        if($i > 0) {
                                if($return[$i]['tag'] == 'NN' 
                                        && strtolower($return[$i-1]['token']) == 'would') {
                                        $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VB';
                                }
                        }

                        // Convert noun to plural if it ends with an s
                        if($return[$i]['tag'] == 'NN' && substr($token, -1) == 's') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'NNS';
                        }

                        // Convert common noun to gerund
                        if(in_array($return[$i]['tag'], $nouns) 
                                        && substr($token, -3) == 'ing') {
                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VBG';
                        }

                        // If we get noun noun, and the second can be a verb, convert to verb
                        if($i > 0) {
                                if(in_array($return[$i]['tag'], $nouns) 
                                                && in_array($return[$i-1]['tag'], $nouns) 
                                                && isset($this->dict[strtolower($token)])) {
                                        if(in_array('VBN', $this->dict[strtolower($token)])) {
                                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VBN';
                                        } else if(in_array('VBZ', 
                                                        $this->dict[strtolower($token)])) {
                                                $return[$i]['tag'] = 'VBZ';
                                        }
                                }
                        }

                        $i++;
                }

                return $return;
        }
}

?>
```

Where `$lexicon` is a very long and large .txt file with records that look like this:

> ```
> Afrika NNP
> Afrikaaner NNP
> Afrikaner JJ NNP
> Afrikanerdom NNP
> Afrikaners NNPS
> Afrique NNP
> Afro-Asian NNP
> Afro-Cuban JJ
> After IN NNP RB IN|JJ
> After-the-fact JJ
> Aftereffects NNS
> Afternoon UH
> Aftershocks NNS
> Afterward RB
> Afterwards RB
> ```

Answer (score 1):

*Not always, less code = less speed*. I tried refactoring your construct and benchmark which is faster using 2 million(30mb) data using you sample data above.

Your code:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

// start of your code
$fh = fopen('trial.txt', 'r'); 
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    $tags = explode(' ', $line);
    $this->dict[strtolower(array_shift($tags)) ] = $tags;
}
fclose($fh);
// end of your code

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "\n FINISHED FOR : $time seconds\n";
```

output is :

```
FINISHED FOR : 5.9890549182892 seconds // first run
FINISHED FOR : 5.6811361312866 seconds // second run
FINISHED FOR : 5.6887800693512 seconds // third run
FINISHED FOR : 5.9396271705627 seconds // fourth run
FINISHED FOR : 5.8988060951233 seconds // fifth run
```

while using this code and using same data:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

// start of new code
$fh = file('trial.txt');
foreach ($fh as $line) {
    $tags = explode(' ', $line);
    $index = $tags[0];
    unset($tags[0]);
    $this->dict[strtolower($index)] = $tags;
}
// end of new code

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "\n FINISHED FOR : $time seconds\n";
```

output is:

```
FINISHED FOR : 4.7662661075592 seconds // first run
FINISHED FOR : 4.7664079666138 seconds // second run
FINISHED FOR : 4.6799538135529 seconds // third run
FINISHED FOR : 4.6740348339081 seconds // fourth run
FINISHED FOR : 4.6929490566254 seconds // fifth run
```

....

Next I Will try to optimize your tag function :)